# Get object value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an object

```
var actions = {
    'photos': function()
    {
        var self = this; // self = actions

        $.get('./data.php?get=photos', function(data)
        {
            self.result = data;
        });
    },
    'videos': function()
    {
        var self = this;

        $.get('./data.php?get=videos', function(data)
        {
            self.result = data;
        });
    }
};
```

Each function creates one more item in `actions` called `result`

Then, instead of `switch` I use this (works good):

```
if (actions[action])
{
    actions[action](); // call a function
    console.log(actions);
    console.log(actions.result);
}
```

`action` is a variable with value `photos` or `videos`.

`console.log(actions)` gives this:

```
Object
message: function ()
messages: function ()
profile: function ()
profile-edit: function ()
result: "<div>...</div>"
__proto__: Object
```

So I think there is `result`item in `actions` with the value `"<div>...</div>"`.

**But**, `console.log(actions.result)` **returns** `undefined`.

**Why?**

I know all this code may be rewrited, but I would like to understand the reason of `undefined`.

Comment: Your question is fairly unclear. Is `action` a reference to `actions.photos` / `actions.videos` (as @dystroy thinks it is), or the string `"photos"` / `"videos"`? What's the `items` in `items[action]();`? If `action` is a reference to `actions.photos`, why are you trying to index into another object using a function reference?

Comment: `items[action]()` is a typo, should be `actions[action]()` instead. Fixed.

Comment: That makes more sense. :-) So `action` is a string (`"photos"` or `"videos"`), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we are dealing with asynchronous requests, we use "callbacks".

A callback is called when an asynchronous request is ready. Your request will get a response, and you send that response with the callback. The callback handles the response.

```
var actions = {
    'photos': function(callback)
    {
        $.get('./data.php?get=photos', callback);
    },
    'videos': function(callback)
    {
        $.get('./data.php?get=videos', callback);
    }
};

var action = 'photos';

actions[action](function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

---

Since you ensist on keeping the values, I would use this structure:

```
var actions = {
    'photos': function()
    {
        $.get('./data.php?get=photos', function() {
            this.__callback('photos', data);
        });
    },

    'videos': function()
    {
        $.get('./data.php?get=videos', function() {
            this.__callback('videos', data);
        });
    },

    '__callback': function(action, data) {
        this.results[action].push(data);
    },

    'results': {
        'photos': [],
        'videos': []
    }
};

var action = 'photos';

actions[action]();

// use a timeout because we are dealing with async requests
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(actions.results); // shows all results
    console.log(actions.results.photos); // shows all photos results
    console.log(actions.results.videos); // shows all videos results
}, 3000);
```

gaaah what a horrible piece of code...

Comment: I would like to keep current structure of `$.get`, because in each `actions` item extra code can be used after `self.result = data`

Comment: @JohnRezza Then run the callback at the end of your anonymous success callback: `$.get("...", function(data) { self.result = data; callback(); })`